# Pod Install Error Mapbox

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hi i am Install pod of Mapbox. I am getting following Error.

The Swift pod `MapboxCoreNavigation` depends upon `MapboxMobileEvents`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

This is my Pod File

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target ‘DailyWages’ do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
     pod 'MapboxNavigation'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Please Help.Any Help Would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"*use_modular_headers!*" helped me.

Add it after this line: "target ‘DailyWages’ do"